# UICollectionView compositional layout: custom item size for remaining space?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm reading Apple's documentation on compositional layout, for following code example:

```swift
func createBasicListLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout { 
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),                                  
                                         heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))    
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)  
  
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),                                          
                                          heightDimension: .absolute(44))    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,                                                   
                                                     subitems: [item])  
  
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)    

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)    
    return layout
}
```

I wonder if, say, there are two items in `group`, one with `.absolute(X)` for width dimension, is it possible to have another item taking up the remaining space in width dimension? Thanks!